# Roelcke precompactness and Ramsey property

Tags: model-theory, descriptive-set-theory, ramsey-theory, topological-dynamics

[A survey by Nguyen Van Thé (2014)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3254v2) has Conjecture 1,
which is that
"every closed oligomorphic
subgroup of $S_∞$ should have a metrizable universal minimal flow with a generic
orbit."  Later, it goes on to say that "it is even possible that this should be
true for a larger class of groups, called Roelcke precompact." (Let me call this Conjecture 1'.) Now, Kwiatkowska (2018) exhibited a group without a metrizable universal minimal flow that is not Roelcke precompact, so we need to stick to Conjecture 1.

How about the converse of Conjecture 1', i.e., the statement that a closed subgroup of $S_∞$ is Roelcke precompact if it has a metrizable universal minimal flow?  Is there a proof or a counterexample?  In absence of either of the two, do people believe it?

Comment: Which paper is Kwiatkowska (2018)? And do you mean to state "which is Roelcke precompact" (not "is not")?

Comment: @user95282 Ola's paper is [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07869) (arxiv link), she showed that $\mathrm{Homeo}(W_P)$ has a comegear orbit on its UMF despite the latter being nonmetrizable. $W_P$ is the generalized Wazewski dendrite for some $P\subseteq\omega+1$ infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The isometry group of the ordered rational Urysohn space is extremely amenable but not Roelcke precompact, which gives a counterexample.